# Your computer was restarted because of a problem -- OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic, driver

My system was working fine, but when I was updating iTunes this problem happened.

```
Sun Apr 12 21:17:23 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff800a017cc2): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f8a7888e0, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000116579dc0, CR3: 0x000000000caf4000, CR4: 0x00000000001627e0
RAX: 0xffffff7f8a78bc60, RBX: 0xffffff8015b3da00, RCX: 0x0000000001500000, RDX: 0xffffff8014580710
RSP: 0xffffff80a3ba3d10, RBP: 0xffffff80a3ba3d40, RSI: 0x0000000000010002, RDI: 0x0000000116579dc0
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0xffffff80164a87d6, R10: 0x0000000000000007, R11: 0x0000000000000003
R12: 0x0000000000000001, R13: 0xffffff8016558a00, R14: 0xffffff80a3ba3d50, R15: 0xffffff8015b3da00
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff7f8a7888e0, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x0000000116579dc0, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x3

Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80a3ba39c0 : 0xffffff8009f2bda1 
0xffffff80a3ba3a40 : 0xffffff800a017cc2 
0xffffff80a3ba3c00 : 0xffffff800a034b73 
0xffffff80a3ba3c20 : 0xffffff7f8a7888e0 
0xffffff80a3ba3d40 : 0xffffff7f8a788d3e 
0xffffff80a3ba3d80 : 0xffffff7f8a788b73 
0xffffff80a3ba3db0 : 0xffffff7f8a787276 
0xffffff80a3ba3e10 : 0xffffff7f8a7875eb 
0xffffff80a3ba3e40 : 0xffffff7f8a78822c 
0xffffff80a3ba3e70 : 0xffffff800a4b3cad 
0xffffff80a3ba3eb0 : 0xffffff800a4b379f 
0xffffff80a3ba3f30 : 0xffffff800a4ae553 
0xffffff80a3ba3f70 : 0xffffff800a4b4443 
0xffffff80a3ba3fb0 : 0xffffff800a0125b7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.visicom.ManyCam.VideoDevice.driver(3.0.11)[AD731C8A-1682-30D4-8817-417E6C85BA32]@0xffffff7f8a786000->0xffffff7f8a7b7fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOVideoFamily(1.2.1)[399D9EDD-0E6F-3C83-B60F-98214134FCD0]@0xffffff7f8a777000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStreamFamily(1.1.0)[A67D63E8-0326-34ED-8E53-E75567C1BEC4]@0xffffff7f8a76b000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
14D131

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4B3A11F4-77AA-3D27-A22D-81A1BC5B504D
Kernel slide:     0x0000000009c00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8009e00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8009d00000
System model name: MacBookAir6,2 (Mac-7DF21CB3ED6977E5)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 3193808358
last loaded kext at 3054492375: com.visicom.ManyCam.VideoDevice.driver  3.0.11 (addr 0xffffff7f8a786000, size 204800)
loaded kexts:
com.visicom.ManyCam.VideoDevice.driver  3.0.11
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.10.22
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.7.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.33.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.0.6
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 67
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck    471.20.7
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIPassThrough   1.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   930.37.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.iokit.IOVideoFamily   1.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStreamFamily  1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.10.22
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.0.6
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUART 2.0.56
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.22
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.14
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   176.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    41.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  263.9.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.20.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  41.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    2.0.56
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 2.0.56
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 2.0.56
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  2.0.56
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookAir6,2, BootROM MBA61.0099.B18, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.13f15
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5000, Intel HD Graphics 5000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E384A544D4C41522D4E544D
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E384A544D4C41522D4E544D
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.4f4 15601, 3 services, 27 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD0128F, 121.33 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 23.6
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the ManyCam https://manycam.com/uninstall/mac to test without it.

[image: ManyCam]

If it works, get a updated version of ManyCam.

Comment: thanks it worked i fixed the problem, much appreciated very thankful, have a good day

Comment: you are welcome, so we can mark this one as DONE :)